# Does MongoDB fetch entire document even if single field is projected?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB Collection for weather data with each document consisting about 50 different weather parameters fields. Simple Example below:

```
{
"wind":7,
"swell":6,
"temp":32,
...
"50th_field":32
}
```

If I only need one field from all documents, say `temp`, my query would be this:

```
db.weather.find({},{ temp: 1})
```

So internally, does MongoDB has to fetch the entire document for just 1 field which was requested(projected)? Wouldn't it be an expensive operation?

I tried MongoDB Compass to benchmark timings, but the time required was <1ms so couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is how to avoid it:

1. create an index on **temp**
2. Use `find(Temp)`
3. turn off **_id** (necessary).

Run:

```
db.coll.find({ temp:{ $ne:null }},{ temp:1, _id:0 })`
```

`{}` triggers collscan because the algorithm tries to match the query fields with project

With `{temp}, {temp, _id:0}` it says: "Oh, I only need temp".

It should also be smart to tell that `{}, {temp, _id:0}` only needs index, but it's not.

Comment: this is not a good answer.. see the edited question when it comes out, please

Comment: what do you mean? @Martian2049

Comment: the review is in process...https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29321128

Comment: @Martian2049 indexes data are always in memory, if you query 1 field that is indexed and run the right query, it will be fast.

Answer (score 1):

MonogDB will **read** all data, however only field `temp` (and `_id`) will be transmitted over your network to the client. In case your document are rather big, then the over all performance should be better when you project only the fields you need to get.

Answer (score 0):

Basically using projection with limiting fields is always faster then fetch full document, You can even use the covered index to avoid examining the documents(no disk IO) the archive better performance.

Check the `executionStats` of demo below, the `totalDocsExamined` was 0! but you must remove the `_id` field in projection because it's not included in index.

See also:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query

```js
> db.test.insertOne({name: 'TJT'})
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "insertedId" : ObjectId("5faa0c8469dffee69357dde3")
}
> db.test.createIndex({name: 1})
{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
  "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
  "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
  "ok" : 1
}

db.test.explain('executionStats').find({name: 'TJT'}, {_id: 0, name: 1})
{
  "queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "memo.test",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
      "name" : {
        "$eq" : "TJT"
      }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "PROJECTION",
      "transformBy" : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : 1
      },
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
          "name" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "name_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
          "name" : [ ]
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
          "name" : [
            "[\"TJT\", \"TJT\"]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
  },
  "executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 1,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
    "executionStages" : {
      "stage" : "PROJECTION",
      "nReturned" : 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
      "works" : 2,
      "advanced" : 1,
      "needTime" : 0,
      "needYield" : 0,
      "saveState" : 0,
      "restoreState" : 0,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "invalidates" : 0,
      "transformBy" : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : 1
      },
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
        "works" : 2,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 0,
        "restoreState" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "keyPattern" : {
          "name" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "name_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
          "name" : [ ]
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
          "name" : [
            "[\"TJT\", \"TJT\"]"
          ]
        },
        "keysExamined" : 1,
        "seeks" : 1,
        "dupsTested" : 0,
        "dupsDropped" : 0,
        "seenInvalidated" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```